# How do I get the index (position) of an element from a json array in presto?

Tags: presto

I'm using Presto, and have two columns.

Column A is a json array which looks like `["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`

Column B is a string value `"cherry"`

All I want to do is look up Column B in the array of Column A, and get the index if they find a match.

I can't find a function to do this easily in Presto documentation anywhere.

I tried `json_array_find`, `position_at`, `element_at`, and different combinations of these functions, but they all either aren't compatible with presto, or return 0 or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `element_at` function along with the `array_position` function.

```sql
SELECT array_position(CAST(json_parse(column_a) AS array<varchar>), column_b) - 1 AS match_index
FROM your_table;
```

This query should return the index (0-based) if a match is found, and `-1` if there is no match.